# KeyEvent to change photos dosen't work, how to activate it?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, keyevent

I want to make switching photo program, using imageView and keyEvent, but when I try to use keyEvent it dosen't work, I was trying add scene.getRoot().requestFocus(); but didn't help, so my question is, why it dosen't work any how could I activate it?

**MenuScreenController.java**

```
    @FXML
public void getNewImageHandler(KeyEvent event) {
    System.out.println(singleFile.getName());
    imgFieldView.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.N) {
            photoSwipCounter++;
            System.out.println("P clicked");
        } else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.P) {
            photoSwipCounter--;
        }
    });

//        if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.N)) {
//            photoSwipCounter++;
//        }
//        if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.P)) {
//            photoSwipCounter--;
//        }

    if (photoSwipCounter < 0) {
        singleFile = selectedImgsList.get(selectedImgsList.size() - photoSwipCounter);
    } else {
        singleFile = selectedImgsList.get(photoSwipCounter);
    }

    image = new Image(singleFile.toURI().toString(),
            900, 400,
            true, true, true);
    imgFieldView.setImage(image);
}
```

As you can see I was trying many methods, by stream, or classic, but it dosen't make change.

**MenuScreen.fxml**

```
<Pane fx:id="menuPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="screensaverfxml.Controllers.MenuScreenController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="imgFieldView" fitHeight="400.0" fitWidth="900.0" layoutX="66.0" layoutY="62.0" onKeyPressed="#getNewImageHandler" onMouseClicked="#imgDoubleClick" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

**ScreenSaverFXML.java**

```
    @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/screensaverfxml/fxmlConfig/MainScreen.fxml"));
    Pane mainPane = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 1000, 700);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Screen Saver");

    primaryStage.show();

   scene.getRoot().requestFocus();
}
```

And ofc I have method to load first photo on imageView and it's work by load it from the folder to the list, but switching to next nope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only nodes that have the focus receive key events. Since you have `scene.getRoot().requestFocus()` it's the root that receives the events. However, you're adding your `EventHandler` to `imgFieldView` and since that node is a descendant of the root it never sees any key events. You need to either have your `imgFieldView` obtain the focus or add your handler to the root node instead.

*Note: You can only request focus once the target `Node` is part of a `Scene`.*

The other problem is your call to `imgFieldView.setOnKeyPressed(...)` in the `getNewImageHandler` method. When you add an event handler via FXML, for instance by using `onKeyPressed="#getNewImageHandler"`, it sets the corresponding `onXXX` property of the node. In your case, it's setting the `onKeyPressed` property of `imgFieldView`. However, in that handler you also set that property which replaces the handler set by the `FXMLLoader`. Your new handler simply increments or decrements the `photoSwipeCounter` field but does nothing with the new value. Your method should look more like:

```
@FXML
public void getNewImageHandler(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.N)) {
        photoSwipeCounter++;
    }
    if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.P)) {
        photoSwipeCounter--;
    }

    // wrap around logic
    if (photoSwipeCounter < 0) {
        photoSwipeCounter = selectedImgsList.size() - 1;
    } else if (photoSwipeCounter >= selectedImgsList.size()) {
        photoSwipeCounter = 0;
    }

    singleFile = selectedImgsList.get(photoSwipeCounter);

    image = new Image(singleFile.toURI().toString(),
            900, 400,
            true, true, true);
    imgFieldView.setImage(image);
}
```

Comment: When I added imgFieldView.requestFocus(); in getNewImageHandler() it started work. But didnt' change photos, when I changed logic about photoSwipeCounter it works as it should so thank u.